# Generic property for Framework element which loaded as content of ToolTip - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datatemplate

I have DataTemplate with FramewrokElement. like in below snippet

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <Button/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="template">
        <TextBlock/>
    </DataTemplate>
```

This template will be assigned to a tool tip like in below code snippet

ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
tooltip.Content = template.LoadContent();

The created tooltip will be set to a UIElement some thing like another content control using ToolTipService.

UIElement uiElement = new uiElement();
ToolTipService.SetToolTip(uiElement,tooltip);

Here, the actual question , tooltip will be some UIElement. can be button, text block, text box, content control, something like combination of UIElements.

The data that bound to the datatemplate should be in view. what is the property that can show the value on that particular UIElement.

For example.

if i have button in DataTemplate, i have to bind to ContentProperty of button and the value will be shown on Button in view when mouse over on uiElement.

if i have TextBlock in DataTemplate, i have to bind to TextProperty of TextBlock and the value will be shown on TextBlock in view when mouse over on uiElement.

Or please suggest me the some other way to overcome it?